# Angular application cache issue on next release

Tags: angular, caching, browser

I have gone through a lot of articles and questions in stackoverflow too regarding cache issue in angular application.
But I got not much exact solution for that.

Every time when we release our angular app that time the user need not to clear cache using `ctrl F5`,
Instead the browser should automatically get latest code from server (I am using angular 6).

How to validate this ? Please show me the best and exact solution that angular suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command: ng build --aot --output-hashing=all

More Info: https://angular.io/cli/build